# Find installed Plugin List in Kibana UI

Tags: elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I'm using Kibana 7.1.1 and I have install plugin using **./bin/kibana-plugin install** command and I can get list using **./bin/kibana-plugin list**.

But Is there any way I can find this Installed Plugin list on Kibana UI?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I'm looking for kibana's plugin list in kibana UI, not ElasticSearch's Plugin list, so I can't accept your answer right now, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `<kibanaurl>/status` page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `_cat/plugins` API, it works with elasticsearch although I have not tested with kibana, more info on this API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-plugins.html

Comment: I have used this API from both Kibana UI and cURL from terminal, and I didn't get any value.
I think this API will only return plugin installed for Elasticsearch not Kibana.

Comment: @AchyutVyas, maybe as I mentioned i used it only in ES